Looking for pulp sci-fi paperback written pre-1976, two men, separated early in the book, find an underground civilization of dim-witted, pale beings
In this dumb pulp novel, two men are exploring a cave and fall through to a vast domed world where a race of small, pale beings regularly crash their go-cart-like vehicles into each other. The protagonist teaches them road rules (among other things) and becomes their leader. They are preparing for a yearly war with another similar race of idiots. I never read the final chapter but I suspect the man's lost colleague has become the leader of the second tribe. The cover depicted a man standing beside a futuristic tank-like vehicle (which had nothing to do with the plot).

This is likely Hidden World (1957) by Stanton A. Coblentz.  You probably recall the 1964 paperback cover, though the tanks actually do have a fair bit to do with the plot.

At one point the protagonist does create traffic laws for the chalk-faces:

For example, there was the matter of the "scootscoots." Having been shocked at the innumerable accidents, which cost hundreds of lives each day and more than once had nearly terminated my own existence, I set about to establish a system of traffic rules. These were really what we of the Overworld would consider simple and reasonable: that all "scootscoots" keep to the right of the road, that green and red lights be installed to guide traffic at intersections, and that no "scootscoot" be permitted to travel faster than two miles a minute. Yet what an uproar was created by these innovations! It was found, indeed, that wherever the new rules were applied, the death-rate fell more than ninety per cent—but what did this mean to the speed-hungry chalk-faces?—nothing—less than nothing!

The Wikipedia page has a plot summary which describes how two people from the Overworld get separated and end up each ruling one of the underground nations Wu and Zu:

While exploring an abandoned silver mine in Nevada, Philip Clay and Frank Comstock are separated from their team and trapped by a cave-in triggered by a series of earthquakes. As they try to find a way out of the trap they come to a corridor with smooth walls and floor. They eventually see light, follow it, and come to a place overlooking a vast cavern, filled with yellow-green light, where a mighty battle plays out before them.
Spotted by the combatants and fired upon, the two men run for their lives and get separated from each other in the confusion. Frank is captured by a group of men with chalk-white faces and taken to a large underground city. [...]
[...] Frank works his way up the social scale and also discovers a hidden way to turn off Wu’s air supply. Using the latter, he deposes the dictator and takes his place.
Frank’s efforts to reform the society of Wu meet so much resistance and resentment that he is compelled to renew the war with Zu, whose own dictator has just been deposed. The new dictator of Zu turns out to be Philip Clay in disguise.  [...]


Stanton A. Coblentz (1896-1982) was an early pulp science fiction writer so I find 1957 rather late for the first publication of one of his novels.  The ISFDB lists the first publication as the March, April, & May 1935 issues of Wonder Stories, and many later ones. https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?186966

@M.A.Golding Note that this publication has a cover that matches the question's description, and its date is given by ISFDb as 1957, not the 1935 date of the serial In Caverns Below from which it is derived.

My memory was quite selective: the cover is indeed relevant as war is a major component of the book. At 13 years old that plot point wasn’t compelling, I guess. I remembered more about the protagonist’s rise to leadership. The book is also much better written than I’d recalled, with even some subversive oblique commentary on the military industrial complex and capitalism.
